# How to persist status messages/icons/notifications through Backbone View render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have `save()` and `destroy()` methods being called on a Model that sits behind a View, both of which display some sort of UI change (or "notification") within the View/template when they succeed or fail; maybe it's a green checkmark for a successful save, a red X for a failed deletion, etc.

However, these `save()` and `destroy()` methods may also re-render the View, either directly via a `render()` call, or indirectly via changed attributes on the model when a successful save or deletion occurs.

**Re-rendering, of course, wipes out these UI notifications, essentially resetting the View to its "neutral," pre-save/delete state.**

Is there a widely-accepted way of persisting these sort of UI notifications through a re-render? Alternatively, is there a way of partially rendering a View/template that may also solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status could be an attribute of the model, which would be reflected in the template after a re-render, e.g. in your view template, something like:

```
<div class="notification notification-<%= status %>>
   <%= getStatusMessage(status) %> (Or whatever, you get the idea, perhaps
                                    status itself is an object with a message)
</div>
```

In this way the status messages would be baked into the same re-render logic.

```
model.set("status", "error"); // re-render with error message
model.set("status", "success"); // re-render with success message
```

Alternatively, the view might maintain its own notifications.  Say the view kept one notification, you might do something like:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  notify: function (message, status) {
    this.notification = {message: message, status: status};
    this.render();
  },

  // and when rendering the template, just merge it into the data
  render: function () {
    var html = myTemplate({notification: this.notification, ...});
    //...
  }
});
```

And in the template:

```
<% if ("undefined" !== typeof notification) { %>
  <div class="notification notification-<%= notification.status %>>
    <%= notification.message %>
  </div>
<% }; %>
```

And back in your code, for example:

```
model.save({
  success: function () { view.notify(someMessage, "success") },
  error: function () { view.notify(someMessage, "error") }
});
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, but I do tend to cringe a little bit at setting a non-data attribute on the Model, as the status message isn't technically Model data. It's really just a notification intended for the end user.

Comment: I do like the second option you've added; keeps the notification out of the model and on the View/template, which makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: That's a pattern I tend to use a lot with views, treating them almost like a view model by mixing in helpers and tailoring the model attributes on render.  Tends to work pretty well I think, although there's also merit to a composite view pattern (a container view for views of multiple models and other pieces of data like status messages).  Marionette does that pretty well and might offer some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is more a question of your `render()` logic than anything else. If when the view is rendered, status messages should persist, then your render method should not affect that div.

Obviously, this can get a little messy within the DOM and your `$el` property of the view though, but you will probably want something like this.

**View**

```
notificationDiv : null,
contentDiv : null,

initialize : function() {
    // set up your notification and content divs here
    this.$el.append(this.notificationDiv).append(this.contentDiv);
}, 

render : function() {
    // have render only affect the content div, maybe something like this
    this.contentDiv.html( howeverYouWantToTemplate({content}) );
},

setStatus : function(status) {
    this.notificationDiv.text(status);
}
```